# KendoUI Angular 2 how to refresh Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am showing a grid in a loop. Each time in the loop I am setting the datasource to a new table which is represented in an array but the grid doesn't change. The columns from the previous table are shown and the new table columns are never shown. The crazy thing is the data is updated ONLY if the columns on table1 also exist in table 2 or 3.

How can I get the grid to update the once the datasource is changed?

```
ChangeGrid(file){
this.fileData = file;
} 

  <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]=fileData [height]='200' [pageSize]="10" [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [filterable]="false" [groupable]="false">
        </kendo-grid>
```

Comment: plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/bBbSF9JEGZ6Ug1WKr6qa?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically replacing your variable which has the reference of `KendoGridBinding` and you are replacing it with your new array, so binding is removed from your variable and is replaced by your array.

To show the changes sophisticatedly, you have to write your custom binding directive, follow the steps: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/data-binding/automatic-operations/

**The shortcut**: You can push or pop the array items, it will retain the binding which is present in your variable

```
ChangeGrid(file){
this.fileData.push(file[0]);
}
```

Comment: I think I may have misworded my question. Instead of adding to a grid datsource array i need the grid to show all new data.  So each loop is a brand new table with different columns and headers.

Comment: When I loop the kendo grid never changes the columns but will try to map the new data to any old columns that may have the same name

Comment: For this purpose, you have to write custom binding directive.

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/data-binding/automatic-operations/#toc-custom-remote-directives

You can write `rebind` method in your directive where you will change the data .

Comment: I've added a plunkr to see what I mean